# AzDo Migration Tool: PBI's to User Story migration not working

Tags: azure-devops-migration-tools

I'm currently using the Azure DevOps Migration Tool to move some work items from an on-prem Azure DevOps collection to a Azure DevOps collection online/cloud.

On the cloud version we are exclusively using an Agile template and as such I need to migrate some project that use the scrum template. This means converting Product Backlog Items to User Storys.

Upon running the migration tool with the WorkItemTypeDefinition set as below

```
  "WorkItemTypeDefinition": {
    "Product Backlog Item": "User Story"
```

Results in an error **"System.Exception: WARNING: Unable to find 'Product Backlog Item' in the target project. Most likley this is due to a typo in the .json configuration under WorkItemTypeDefinition!"**

There doesn't seem to be a typo nor anything else obvious wrong that I can see. Other WITs seem processed okay. Can anyone help?

See snippet for expanded view of configuration.json

[configuration.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKuvz.jpg)

Comment: Looks like a bug: moved to https://github.com/nkdAgility/azure-devops-migration-tools/issues/626

Comment: Should be resolved by https://github.com/nkdAgility/azure-devops-migration-tools/issues/626

Comment: Hi @MrHinsh-MartinHinshelwood thanks for the quick bug fix! I have spent the afternoon trying to run the updated tool but I am now getting -
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: credentials

I'm pretty sure the version before the bug fix got further than that (this happens almost immediately). I am a project collection admin on both collections. Can you help?

Comment: Yup, that was a second bug fix that went into v11.6.1. Sorry for the trouble, we have been doing refactoring in preparation for some major feature updates.

Comment: Hi @MrHinsh-MartinHinshelwood I've been testing again today with version 11.6.1 and I am getting a lot of empty PBI's on my Target project after specifying "WorkItemTypeDefinition": {"sourceWorkItemTypeName": "targetWorkItemTypeName"} again.

During the run, I get a lot of errors that describe a "ERR] System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssServiceResponseException: Page not found." Is that related?

Comment: You have work item type changes in history. Thats currently not supported due to an API snafu and you need to set `SkipToFinalRevisedWorkItemType` to `true`